# The latest edition of The Overflow's content has incorrectly generated quote and apostrophe characters

Tags: bug, blog, html-entities, the-overflow

[The Overflow #132](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/01/the-overflow-132-the-2022-dev-survey-results/) has some unescaped/incorrectly generated apostrophes and quotation marks.

Here's a screenshot of the problematic content in question:

[image: Screenshot of blog content, with two unescaped quotation marks and one incorrectly escaped apostrophe]

In particular:

> `The term to use when trash talking previous tech stacks is &quot;technical debt.&quot;`
>
> `Farting in a king&#x27;s general direction may not have been treason, but cartoon farts are probably safer.`

Could we fix up those odd bits of punctuation?

Comment: I see the [issue from #129](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418634/11407695) [and likely earlier] happily lives on, sigh. &#x57;&#x68;&#x61;&#x74;&#x20;&#x61;&#x20;&#x73;&#x68;&#x61;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x21;

Comment: &#x54;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6c;&#x79;&#x2c;&#x20;&#x77;&#x65;&#x20;&#x6d;&#x75;&#x73;&#x74;&#x20;&#x6c;&#x69;&#x76;&#x65;&#x20;&#x69;&#x6e;&#x20;&#x74;&#x68;&#x65;&#x20;&#x64;&#x61;&#x72;&#x6b;&#x65;&#x73;&#x74;&#x20;&#x74;&#x69;&#x6d;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x69;&#x6e;&#x65;&#x2e;

Comment: &#x49;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x65;&#x64;&#x2C;&#x20;&#x74;&#x68;&#x65;&#x20;&#x64;&#x61;&#x72;&#x6B;&#x65;&#x73;&#x74;&#x20;&#x6F;&#x66;&#x20;&#x74;&#x68;&#x65;&#x6D;&#x20;&#x61;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x2C;&#x20;&#x77;&#x68;&#x65;&#x72;&#x65;&#x20;&#x48;&#x54;&#x4D;&#x4C;&#x20;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x74;&#x69;&#x74;&#x69;&#x65;&#x73;&#x20;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6E;&#x20;&#x72;&#x61;&#x6D;&#x70;&#x61;&#x6E;&#x74;&#x21;

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of [Let's escape The Overflow Newsletter entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380826/335251), even though that post is newer, because it covers this blog post as well – and I've posted an official answer there.