# Escaped HTML in The Overflow blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, html-entities, the-overflow

There are several instances of escaped HTML in the latest issue of The Overflow, [Sufficiently advanced HTML conversion feels like magic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/29/the-overflow-136-sufficiently-advanced-code-completion-feels-like-magic/):

[image]

Further down there's another `&#x27;`.

Comment: Related: [The latest edition of The Overflow's content has incorrectly generated quote and apostrophe characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380010/the-latest-edition-of-the-overflows-content-has-incorrectly-generated-quote-and). On MSO (a while back): [There&#x27;s no escape from HTML entities on the Blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418634/therex27s-no-escape-from-html-entities-on-the-blog). Maybe it's time we make a general post asking this to be fixed for all past and upcoming blog posts.

Comment: I feel like there's a certain irony here

Comment: I couldn't resist - it's Friday after all ...

Comment: @Justin we can't ask to prevent future mistakes, the staff working on the blog work in a certain way, and we can't change that. (Publish, wait for feedback telling what's wrong, and when they notice the feedback, fix.)

Comment: What is the underlying reason for this? Blog content that gets copied from somewhere else and some of it double escaped before it enters the WordPress source? (The WordPress source is a sort of pseudo  HTML (e.g., significant hard line breaks, but back to 1995 for styling as italics)).

Comment: Perhaps it is for Popper to make to a simple tool to detect and/or prevent this problem. And then write about it in a series of blog posts afterwards? It would also give insight into how efficient Stack Exchange, and in particular Stack Overflow, is as a research tool (read-only mode). E.g., how easy is it to find the solutions (presuming they already exist)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum lol that would never happen. But yeah, sounds good. (Such a magic tool to detect human errors and fix them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the escaped HTML in this blog has been unescaped (a.k.a. fixed!) -

[image]

Comment: Until the next blog...

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for taking the time to report this problem.

I've spoken with the Marketing team, which runs the blog; apparently, this was due to an error in our content management system. That issue has now been fixed, so this shouldn't happen again in future blog posts – but that doesn't automatically fix these HTML issues in previously published blog posts.

In the meantime, the HTML issues in this particular blog post have been fixed, as [Justin's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380829/335251) notes.

Comment: It's already in your system via a status-review retag, but you may want to check out [this more comprehensive post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380826/622284) about the unescaped characters that span a large number of The Overflow's editions.

Comment: @Spevacus: Yep, I'm planning to respond to that one (and to an MSO post reporting the same issue) momentarily.