# Unloaded characters in SO blog title

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, special-characters, regression

The blog title of [this new blog post posted today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/18/beware-the-scammers-posing-as-tech-recruiters-ep-497%ef%bf%bc%ef%bf%bc/?cb=1&_ga=2.165613439.1784471642.1665066606-727062133.1659436658) is broken:

> Beware the scammers posing as tech recruiters (Ep. 497)￼￼

Comment: Does this really need to be brought up every time it happens (no offence to you, DialFrost :)? It seems like a single review would solve (copy+paste?) issues like these. Maybe there should be Review Queues for the SO blog—that seems to work for more sites here :D

Comment: @Joachim That could be another question possibly! Not sure if that's a viable option ... meh maybe :3

Comment: @Joachim yes it must be reported otherwise it will stay bugged. They do **not** review their own blog posts. "Fire and forget" is easy when busy.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard But they *can start* doing that :) If I keep getting the same complaints about something in my control, I'd rather try to solve the problems myself than wait for someone else to point them out again. Especially if it's intended to be seen by as large an audience as possible. More crudely: why should we bother about something we have little to no stake in?

Comment: @Joachim haha, wish you would get hired to work for Stack Exchange, their blog surely needs someone with your approach. Currently, as facts prove, that's not how they work. They publish with glaring bugs, wait for someone to report, then sometimes fix, sometimes [leaving the bugs in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380944/152859), (As it's not worth their time to fix.)

Comment: @Slate this has been fixed, any reason there's no [tag:status-completed] tag here?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Eh, yeah. I was on the edge about it 'cause this isn't the result of a misbehaving system we can fix directly. But rereading, it's just about this one blog post, so, makes sense.

Comment: As a note, I'd suggest including a screenshot of the "broken" title you see alongside your quote of the text in the future, since it's not similarly "broken" for everyone (it just looks like a blank space to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally fixed! The ￼￼ is removed:

> Beware the scammers posing as tech recruiters (Ep. 497)

Hopefully [@Journeyman_Geek's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382988/if-you-dont-look-good-we-dont-look-good-could-there-be-more-aggressive-copy) means no more of these bug reports have to be posted!

Comment: No worry the ￼￼  will be back.