# Consider having someone spot-check the rendering of blog posts after they are posted

Tags: feature-request, blog, stack-exchange-team

We've had a few bugs about issues with the rendering of blog posts, including [unloaded characters in the blog post title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382982/unloaded-characters-in-so-blog-title), [broken links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415297), [HTML entities appearing in the text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418634/208273), etc. After discussing the idea with @Journeyman_Geek and @Ryan_M (idea from @Joachim & @Journeyman_Geek), I think that having someone at Stack Exchange check the rendering of blog posts after they go up as a part of the standard publishing process would be a good idea.

As [@Ryan_M helped lay out in a nice message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9324051#9324051):

> Issues like this undermine the work that the marketing team puts into preparing these posts. Having a checklist that includes items like spot-checking that the post is rendered correctly, as well as addressing the causes of past bugs to prevent them from recurring, [as was done for the HTML entities issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419590/208273), would ensure that their work is displayed in the best possible light.

Additionally, there wouldn't be any more complaints or bug reports continuously streaming into meta about character issues in the blog.

Comment: As [discussed here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9324234#9324234), closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell This post was submitted two hours earlier than Journeyman's post, albeit, on the same day.

Comment: Yes, I read the comments in chat. I think DialFrost was very generous.

Comment: Well, JMG did ask to leave this to him, it was probably missed. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9324228#9324228

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard That was **after** I posted this :3

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why ping me? I am already well aware of the timeline, hence the comment linking back to the chat conversation where there was consent to close this one as a duplicate of the newer one. What is expected of me here, why am I needed?