# If you don't look good, we don't look good – could there be more aggressive copy editing of the blog?

Tags: support, blog

Admittedly – I'm the denizen of MSE who gets edited the most often. I've a community who reads my posts and spends the effort and time to fix up my quirks.

There are a significant number of posts about random characters that don't render properly – often ￼, errant line breaks and others under [the blog tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) here. On one hand – it reflects the community's willingness to report such issues.

On the other – to a significant extent, the blog is a tool used to communicate to the 'broader' internet – customers of the paid products, and folks in the peripheries of the community. The quality of the blog reflects on both the company as well as their products and ... this sort of 'minor' error doesn't reflect the effort that's put into many of these posts and work the company does. While I suspect *some* of this are tooling issues – it feels a lot like these could be caught by proofreading after publication or at least at some stage where the 'final' rendering is done.

As such, could the folks who work on the blog put something in place to check on their posts at the appropriate time to handle these minor formatting issues and errant characters to shorten the loop for fixing it?

Comment: Isn't this the same as posted 1 hour ago: [Consider having someone spot-check the rendering of blog posts after they are posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382987)

Comment: @bad_coder https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382987/consider-having-someone-spot-check-the-rendering-of-blog-posts-after-they-are-po?noredirect=1#comment1277282_382987

Comment: @bad_coder yes it's the same. But this one might be better phrased, so better think twice before deciding which to close as dupe of which.

Comment: A lot of these errors seem like technical issues with the rendering of the content that may not show up in whatever they're being previewed in.  I'm not sure checking _before_ publishing would reliably catch such errors, and so I'd suggest instead spot-checking the rendering _after_ publishing, perhaps as part of a standard "go live" checklist for blog posts.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the [OBJ] characters are added only after publishing, and not seen in preview, so "something in place to check on their posts before they're publicly published" won't help.

Comment: @RyanM In my experiences in wordpress - there's usually a way to publish a post but hide it...  I'll adjust to reflect after tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeek but are they using WordPress now? Think they switched to use something else.

Comment: At the moment I'm pretty sure its a outsourced wordpress instance. I might be wrong, but if so, same feeling, different tool :D

Comment: Was there a recent blog entry that merited this attention?

Comment: It used to be a lot worse on the Stack Overflow blog. I *think* copy editing by someone else than the author is now part of the workflow. I would be surprised if an automatic tool could achieve such a high hit rate.

Comment: @Mari-Lou any recent blog post. That's the problem. :/

Comment: [This was the most recent one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382982/unloaded-characters-in-so-blog-title) but the blog tag has quite a few.

Comment: Is the copy-editing the real problem, or is it just a symptom of a blog with low quality content?

Comment: I would say that's a different problem - which probably would be tackled in another question. But its very much something I brought up before, and needs a lot of interal debate over what the actual goals of the blogs are.